# Is it ok to have a collection<ABC> in class ABC? Is it good practice?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have a class suppose ABC, inside that class I have a collection of type ABC, Is it good practice, in what conditions we should try this approach?

```
Public Class ABC

{
   Public Collection<ABC> abcCollection{get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Would that create a paradox? For each time you create an object of ADC it calls another (in the collection).

Comment: That'd be true if the OP's code created new instances in the classes constructor, @Highace2, which the code above doesn't do.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta he still needs to populate the collections and then it would be this paradox again.

Comment: Nope, @Highace2, not if it's done in the right places. Basically: not the constructor.

Comment: If you're going to post code, you might as well try to make it valid, and preferably compilable.

Comment: It would make more sense to specify the concrete use case for which  you are considering this. There are plenty of examples when this could be useful, but to give specific conditions for an unspecific use case is quite impossible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this approach when you want create a `tree structure.`For example you create a Node class and your nodes migth contain child nodes and so on like:

```
public class Node 
{
   public Node Parent { get; set; }
   public ICollection<Node> Childrens { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There are cases in which you may want to associate a class with a collection of the same class.  For example::

```
public class Person
{
    public Collection<Person> Family { get; set; }
    public Collection<Person> Children { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Sure, no problem whenever you need your entity to have a list of the same entity. Plenty of examples to think of:

- Parent => Children
- Menu => SubMenu
- ...